# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for scraping data from a webstie

Tags: python

I would like to print the price of something on a website every second but I get the error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.roblox.com/catalog/20573078/Shaggy"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
newprice = soup.find("span", {"class": "text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"}).text
a = 1

while a == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(newprice())
```

Comment: i forgot to remove the ``` at the end sorry first time using this

Comment: `print(newprice)`

Comment: Use the [edit] button to edit your question if needed.

Comment: I want to make the price update, this only shows the price for when you execute the code and the price changes often which is what I want to see

Comment: then you need to retrieve the data from the website inside your loop. `requests.get` is where you fetch the content from the site... you're correct that within your while loop, the only thing you're doing is sleeping and printing a string. Just move the code at the top inside the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a function, not the variable. Simply just use:

```
print(newprice)
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**:

The price you are scraping won't update because you have already put the information in that variable. In order to achieve what you are wanting you will need to scrape in the loop as well, like so:

```
url = "https://www.roblox.com/catalog/20573078/Shaggy"
a = 1

while a == 1:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    newprice = soup.find("span", {"class": "text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"}).text
    time.sleep(1)
    print(newprice)
```

This will make it so every time that while loop is ran it gets the data from the website.

Comment: I want to make the price update, this only shows the price for when you execute the code and the price changes often which is what I want to see

Comment: @aaaaa Then you cannot use Beautifulsoup or Requests as this only gets static html

Comment: Or just make multiple requests

Comment: Solved by @Insula

Comment: @aaaaa Selenium webdriver can be used to grab dynamic Javascript generated values from web pages

Comment: Well, technically there's nothing stopping OP from using BeautifulSoup, but it requires the page is re-downloaded every time or the contents will obviously stay the same. Pulling the full webpage every second is slow and wasteful, though, so any alternative that doesn't require it to be downloaded in its entirety each time is definitely preferable. Even better would be if there's an option to subscribe to changes to that particular value, but that's rarely an option in reality when you don't control the source.

Comment: @frippe agreed, another library should be used or they should just make it so it scrapes every 5 minutes or so and emails them if the price has changed. but it is entirely up to them i guess.